# Add/modify overlay content of interactive livestream video

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I'm building a web app for management live-stream video with HLS protocol. I have a CMS with vuejs to manage the streaming contents, now, api responses to list of live-stream channel, that includes url of livestream .m3u8.

Problem:

- From livestream info from api response, I want to add additional content to current livestream video to allow user interact with while watch livestream to create interactive livestream video. The additional content are html, such as: input form, links, etc... and it's display overlay of livestream video screen at a specific position. The below image is a sample:
  [image]
- After creating additional contents, I will publish its by call api to submit this change.
- Then the changes update to user, and user can interact with overlay content.

I dont know the best solution to add/modify the overlay content for easy maintaining
I hope you can help resolve this problem.
Thanks you,

Comment: `I will publish its by call api to submit this change` which API are you going to use for that?

Comment: That is just my idea to create overlay content and broadcast it to users. Can you give a another solution?

Comment: another solution? that implies there is a solution already. If there is a solution, what's wrong with it?